# How to take ID numbers from a SQL Server table using Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have been training for database and C# programming concepts as a beginner. I just created a table in SQL Server and inserted some image files into it.

I also created a form project to save images to that DB table and retrieve to show them in a picturebox.

I am trying to get ID numbers and load to a combobox so I can choose the ID number of the related image. I managed to save image files to DB but I couldn't retrieve the ID numbers into the combobox.

I kindly ask for an easy explanation and some suggestions from you. You can check my code out below.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString());

        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog fop = new OpenFileDialog();
            fop.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            fop.Filter = "[JPG,JPEG]|*.jpg";

            if (fop.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream FS = new FileStream(@fop.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                byte[] img = new byte[FS.Length];
                FS.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FS.Length));

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveImage", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //loadImageIDs();
                MessageBox.Show("Image Save Successfully!!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Image to save!!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString());

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("ReadImage",con2);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@imgId", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
                  Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); // I am not sure if this line is correct to get images from the table using "ReadImage" procedure.

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd2;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // I have a problem within this code block, I think :)
    {
        SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString());

        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("ReadAllImageIDs", con3);
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter dc = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dc.SelectCommand = cmd3;

        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        dc.Fill(dtt);

        comboBox1.DataSource = dtt;

        //dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to set your [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your [`ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). e.g.

```
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
```

It is also a good idea, when using objects that implement [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter) to use `using` blocks to ensure they are disposed of correctly. So your method might become:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dtt = new DataTable();
    using (var con3 = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString()))
    using (var cmd3 = new SqlCommand("ReadAllImageIDs", con3))
    {
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using(var dc = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            dc.SelectCommand = cmd3;
            dc.Fill(dtt);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dtt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        }
    }
}
```

You can also shortcut a bit of this with the [`SqlDataAdapter` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2d3kh8d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes select command, and connection string as parameters, so you could simplify to:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dtt = new DataTable();

    using (var dc = new SqlDataAdapter("ReadAllImageIDs", DBHandler.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        dc.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dc.Fill(dtt);
    }
    comboBox1.DataSource = dtt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
}
```

As another note, it is generally a good idea to separate your Data Access Layer (DAL) from your UI. So you might have a separate class, possibly in a separate library:

```
public class ImageService
{
    public static void SaveImage(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] img;
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            img = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
        }
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString()))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveImage", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    public static DataTable GetAllImageIDs
    {
        var dtt = new DataTable();

        using (var dc = new SqlDataAdapter("ReadAllImageIDs", DBHandler.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            dc.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dc.Fill(dtt);
        }
        return dtt;
    }
}
```

Then within your UI you simply have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
    {
        OpenFileDialog fop = new OpenFileDialog();
        fop.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        fop.Filter = "[JPG,JPEG]|*.jpg";

        if (fop.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ImageService.SaveImage(fop.FileName);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    comboBox1.DataSource = ImageService.GetAllImageIDs();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
}
```

Comment: "ID" will be my related column name in the table right?

Comment: Yes, just use the name of the column in the datatable for what you want to display, and what you want the value to be. I wasn't sure what columns your procedure returned, so had to guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.My next step'll be implementing a picturebox to show the images :)

Comment: I appreciate your additional comments and arrangements also.

Comment: Are you using the `FileNames` property instead of the `FileName` property? You would need to loop through each file name in `FileNames` and save each one? If you are still stuck, I think you may need to ask a new question with your updated code.

Comment: Ok I will open another thread if I cannot handle it.Thank you again I will try to use loop approach now.

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear if you are struggling with the combobox or the SQL.

This should give you a good start:

```
        List<string> ids = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        ids.Add(rdr["NameOfIsField"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        MyListBox.DataSource = ids;
```

Consider:

- What you stored procedure is returning
- Whether displaying IDs to a user is meaningful

Comment: Sorry - typing at the same time as @GarethD