# How to update a sql database?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Does somebody know how to update a SQL database using a windows form?

I mean, I have a function to make the connection and when I use the select function it works, but I can't modify it.

I'm using this to add a new element "`insert into [database name] ([name of the row]) values ([value I want to insert])`"

Comment: show some code how your executing the insert statement.

Comment: And you want to update the database from the code? Or you bind the select result into datatable?

Answer (score 1):

please visit [SQL Database Tutorial: Understanding Your Database Structure](https://blog.udemy.com/sql-database-tutorial/) to understand how actually database store records.
Refer few syntax that may help you
to insert/update records in table

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

for update records in table

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an  question  exactly about this thread asked by me -->[How to take ID numbers from a SQL Server table using Visual C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423626/how-to-take-id-numbers-from-a-sql-server-table-using-visual-c-sharp).

Maybe it can help you it is worth having a look at it.